# What's the best way to limit gRPC connection time using vertx-grpc?

Tags: grpc, vert.x, grpc-java, grpc-kotlin

I'm currently using [eclipse-vertx/vertx-grpc](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-grpc/) in Kotlin and I'm wondering what the best way to limit connection time is. I'm trying to bypass the fact that gRPC uses persistent connections to make better use of L3/L4 load-balancers, yet I'm having a hard time defining Keepalive configuration as stated in the [official gRPC docs](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/keepalive/).

Any tips on how to configure this server-side using the Vertx implementation? Thanks in advance.